# Links not showing up in PDF output

Tags: hyperref

I have an odd problem with hyperlinks (using `hyperref`). When the link description and the url are identical, everything works fine, like so:

But when I try to post a url with a description, like so:

```
\href{http://www.wikipedia.org/}{Wikipedia}
```

The link doesn't work. That is, it shows up in TexShop when I typeset, but if I open the PDF in Preview or in Chrome, it doesn't even register as a link (the cursor doesn't change into a hand).

Please let me know if I'm omitting any important info, I'm new to Latex.

Thanks so much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I have noticed that different PDF viewers display links differently. Some don't show the link at all. Best to try with `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}` to check that they are working.  If that does nor solve it, I recommend you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.